# constructor por copia en c++

Tags: c++, poo

Buen dia! Queria hacerles una consulta: soy nuevo viendo c++, pero he visto que cuando crean objetos, al hacer el constructor por copia, cuando definen al metodo lo que le pasan es la posicion de memoria del objeto el cual copian, y a partir de ahi trabajan con eso. Queria preguntar por que cuando se define escribe como si se pasara la posicion de memoria del objeto, en lugar de pasarle el objeto en si mismo, y luego en el main se muestra como si se pasara el objeto propiamente dicho. Por ejemplo:

```
    class vector {
    private:
        float x,y,z;
    public:
        vector();
        vector(float, float, float);
        vector(const vector &);
        float prim() const;
        float seg() const;
        float ter() const;
    }
    vector::vector() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    vector::vector(float x2, float y2, float z2) {
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
        z = z2;
    }
    vector::vector(const vector &v) {
        x = v.prim();
        y = v.seg();
        z = v.ter();
    }

float vector::prim() const
{
    return x;
}

float vector::seg() const
{
    return y;
}

float vector::ter() const
{
    return z;
}
    int main(){
     vector a(4,2,1);
     vector b(a);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: es porque en C++ existen directivas de acceso, no uses C es obsoleto, el constructor copia puede acceder a los metodos publicos del otro objeto para asi copiarlo, no es como en otro lenguajes donde esto es violado. por ejemplo segun tu codigo, cualesquier objeto no puede acceder directamente a `x,y,z` porque son atributos priivados, tienes q crear un metodo para cada una de las variables para retornar su valor, analizando la sintaxis es posible acceder a los atributos del otro objeto porq se usa `&` que tiene mas prioridad que el `const` pero no puedes modificarlos, solo nombrarlos.

Comment: sisi. igual esto es para la universidad asi que de todas formas necesito usar c++. pasa que me aparecio esa duda...esto es un extracto de un codigo que hice

Answer (score 1):

> cuando definen al metodo lo que le pasan es la posicion de memoria del objeto el cual copian, y a partir de ahi trabajan con eso.

No se pasa la posición de memoria sino una referncia (estamos en C++, no en C).

Y se hace así para evitar crear copias recursivas del objeto. Si alguien hiciese esto:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;

  Test(Test t)
  {
    var = t.var;
  }    
};
```

En el momento en el que se tuviese que llamar al constructor copia se tendría que hacer antes una copia temporal del objeto original para almacenarla en `t`. Al crear esa copia se entraría en el constructor copia otra vez y esto originaría otra copia, que provocaría otra llamada al constructor... y así hasta que la pila se desborda.

Al usar referencias se evitan las copias y con ello esta problemática de la llamada recursiva.

Adicionalmente, la referencia se marca como constante para evitar que, por error, el objeto original pueda verse modificado.

Comment: pero justamente una referencia no es la posicion de memoria donde se encuentra almacenado el objeto? Y lo de la modificacion del objeto original no se arregla usando el const?

Comment: @F.Riggio si lo almacenas en un puntero sí, pero una referencia es ligeramente diferente a un puntero. Una referencia garantiza que el objeto referenciado existe (no puedes pasarle un puntero nulo), no se puede cambiar la referencia una vez se ha establecido y para acceder a los miembros de una referencia usas `.` en vez de `->`. En este caso no sería correcto hablar de direcciones de memoria

Comment: ah ya entiendo....sisi, vi un caso que tenias un objeto con un puntero y para referirte al puntero del objeto usabas ->....pasa que vengo de programar durante un año en C y es otra mentalidad completamente diferente la que hay que tener en C++....muchas gracias!!!

Comment: entonces cada vez que pase un objeto a una funcion o un metodo siempre voy a tener que llamar a una referencia en realidad

Comment: no. Depende de cada caso. Además con los últimos estándares el pasar las cosas por referencia empieza a perder cierto sentido. Son conceptos algo complejos... conforme adquieras experiencia los irás entendiendo mejor

Comment: Supongo...igual hasta ahora los ejemplos que vi donde se usan los datos de los punteros se pasan las referencias. Gracias igual!!! Pensé que era algo sencillo como en C reconocer la diferencia

Comment: y te hago una ultima consulta que me surgio: donde dice `float ter() const;` por ejemplo, ahi pide mantener constante las variables que use esa funcion, no es asi? porque estuve buscando un poco como se usa el const y en todos lados lo escriben antes de lo que quieren hacer constante....

Comment: @F.Riggio ese `const` indica que la funcion no puede modificar variables miembro del objeto. Tampoco puede llamar a otras funciones miembro que no sean `const`